# wxPython script hanging for unknown reason

Tags: android, python, wxpython

This is my script. For some reason it doesn't work anymore. It has done previously. Can someone track down any potential errors?

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python

import wx
import os
TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'jmtpfs mounter'

def create_menu_item(menu, label, func):
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu, -1, label)
    menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, func, id=item.GetId())
    menu.AppendItem(item)
    return item

class TaskBarIcon(wx.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
    self.off=wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap("android_off.png"))
    self.SetIcon(self.off)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)
    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Mount', self.mount)
        create_menu_item(menu, 'UnMount', self.unmount)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
        return menu
    def on_left_down(self, event):
        print 'Tray icon was left-clicked.'
    def mount(self, event):
        retvalue = os.system("jmtpfs ~/Nexus")
        print retvalue
    self.on=wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap("android_on.png"))
    self.SetIcon(self.on)
    def unmount(self, event):
        retvalue = os.system("fusermount -u ~/Nexus")
    print retvalue
    self.off=wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap("android_off.png"))
    self.SetIcon(self.off)
    def on_exit(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)

def main():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    TaskBarIcon()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running a trace gives this:

mounter.py(17):     self.SetIcon(self.off)
 --- modulename: _windows, funcname: SetIcon
_windows.py(2174):         return *windows*.TaskBarIcon_SetIcon(*args, **kwargs)
mounter.py(18):         self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)
 --- modulename: _core, funcname: Bind
_core.py(3916):         assert isinstance(event, wx.PyEventBinder)
_core.py(3917):         assert handler is None or callable(handler)
_core.py(3918):         assert source is None or hasattr(source, 'GetId')
_core.py(3919):         if source is not None:
_core.py(3921):         event.Bind(self, id, id2, handler)
 --- modulename: _core, funcname: Bind
_core.py(3994):         for et in self.evtType:
_core.py(3995):             target.Connect(id1, id2, et, function)
 --- modulename: _core, funcname: Connect
_core.py(3875):         return *core*.EvtHandler_Connect(*args, **kwargs)
_core.py(3994):         for et in self.evtType:
mounter.py(44):     app.MainLoop()
 --- modulename: _core, funcname: MainLoop
_core.py(8010):         wx.PyApp.MainLoop(self)
 --- modulename: _core, funcname: MainLoop
_core.py(7306):         return *core*.PyApp_MainLoop(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Where does it exit? btw, you should read PEP8 when you have some time

Comment: I have no idea. I am not a python programmer, I just found a tutorial, and edited to my purpose. It used to work, but now it suddenly don't. I haven't changed any installed packages. I tried making a init script to launch it at boot, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Well, #1 you should at least make an attempt to understand any code you put in your system. Blind copy paste is a bad idea. #2 "it doesn't work anymore" is a very vague problem and without an error message, test case, or even just a description of what you expect to see and what you actually see then it is very very unlikely we can help you. Have you tried debugging the code at all?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce your error while debugging your code in PyDev. However, I found a whole host of errors I had to fix because the code would even execute. After fixing them the code ran fine.

First, your error states that the "handler" in your `self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)` call is `None`. In this case, it means `self.on_left_down` is `None`. However, we can see that there is a function `on_left_down(self, event)`, so that was my first hint that something was wrong with your code. The second hint was that the stack trace seemed to include that `Bind()` call as part of the line `self.SetIcon(self.off)`, which made no sense.

And that's when I noticed that your indentation was horrible. In languages like Java, everything between the `{}` is part of a function and thus indentation is just to make your code easier to read. In Python indentation **much more important**. It is how you denote something as being part of a function or not. How do you tell if a line of code is still part of a loop? You check the indentation. `__init__()`, `mount()`, and `unmount()` all contain lines that are indented too far left, thus are running even before `__init__()` has run, possibly leading to these `None` values.

Second, you must be using an old tutorial as `wx.PySimpleApp` is deprecated. I had to write my own simple `wx.App` before the code would execute (my entire `wx.App` was only 4 lines long including declarations. I'm sure you can find a simple example of how to do this yourself).

Finally, a plea: Please never ever **ever** blindly use code you found in a tutorial, especially if you aren't familiar in the language. You said you aren't a python programmer, so why did you choose wxPython? Do you know C? wxPython is based on wxWidgets, a GUI toolkit for C. Do you know Java? There are many GUI toolkits for Java. I'm sure you can find something that does what you need in a language you understand. By putting code that you do not understand into your application you are really just putting in a new piece that might fail and if it does then you have no way of fixing it.

I don't know you and I don't know your expertise so I'm giving you benefit of the doubt *this time* but I will need to see a lot more effort on your part next time or I won't post an answer.

Best of luck.